# How to write a directory listing to a text file on Windows?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, scripting, notepad

I have a folder that contains over 40,000 video files.

I want to be able to list them all in a text file

I've used the command:

```
@echo off
set dirpath=%location
dir %dirpath% /-p /o:gn > "%dirpath%\DirContents.txt"
exit
```

However, this just  list the directory command thats in cmd.

I want to be able to do this: have a text file that has:

```
File Name, Date Modified
```

Comment: What is `/-p`? [`DIR` at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) doesn't mention it, and that's very nearly the best reference for CMD that I have found.

Comment: Also, what, exactly, are you getting, and what would you like to see instead. (And also, is a PowerShell solution acceptable?)

Comment: Yes, please show what you get and what you want.

Comment: The output i get from running this command is exactly like doing dir in cmd using the -p is for me populating it later on the notepad.

Comment: Also, i dont mind what kind of script it is written in even Java, as i understand Java as well, im just looking for best way this can be done

Comment: `for %%I in ("%location%") do @echo/%%~I  %%~tI`

Comment: By the way: -1 for the very poor question title...

Comment: Oh wow, ok, didn't know how stack overflow worked when asking questions so this was my first attempt, i do better research next time

Comment: I've removed the second issue from this post, as it is sufficiently different from the main problem that it deserves a separate post on its own.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import time

with open("DirContents.txt","w") as fOut:
    fOut.write("FileName, DateModified\n")
    files = glob.glob("~/Videos/*")
    for fName in files:
        stat = time.ctime(os.stat(fName).st_mtime)
        fOut.write("\""+ fName + "\", \"" + stat+"\"\n")
```

Comment: What language is this? It is definitely not `CMD`'s batch language, it's not PowerShell, and it doesn't look like either VBScript or JScript.

Comment: Sorry. That was python. I will submit a batch file soon.

Comment: you can use the forfiles directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using PowerShell. If you are on a supported version of Windows, it will have PowerShell.

Run this in a cmd.exe shell.

```
SET "LOCATION=C:\src\t"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Path %LOCATION% |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { '{0},{1}' -f @($_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime) }"
```

If you can use PowerShell without cmd.exe, it is even easier. Run this in a PowerShell shell.

```
$Location = 'C:\src\t'
Get-ChildItem -Path $Location |
    ForEach-Object {'{0},{1}' -f @($_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime)} |
    Out-File -FilePath "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\DirContents.txt" -Encoding ascii
```

If you want to just stick with the old ways, run this in a cmd.exe shell.

```
FORFILES /P C:\src\t /M *.txt /C "cmd /c ECHO @file,@fdate @ftime"
```

Comment: Hi I have tried all 3, it does not work.  The first one gives the error At D:\Location\checkDir.ps1:3 char:40
+     "Get-ChildItem -Path %LOCATION% |" ^
+                                        ~
Unexpected token '^' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Then on the 2nd one doesnt output the file to a text file, 

The last one just gives the date and time of when the log is made

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @JakePearson - I am guessing that the first code was run in a PowerShell shell. It is written to run in a cmd.exe shell. I am revising the PowerShell code to write to a file. I would not write it in the same directory as the files.